# Python: monster list need monster help, how do I fill my list the proper way?

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I started with Python yesterday and for my first project I want to make monsters battle each other.

I'm still at the start and I want to fill a list with monsters I created. My monster function asks for how many monsters it should create and gives back a list with all of them.

Somehow my code is wrong and only gives back one single monster :(

```
def create_monster(number):
    monster = [0] * number

    for i in monster:
        """monster = [ID,GENDER,NAME,HP,ATK,DEF,SATK,SDEF,AGIL,]"""

        monster[i] = [monster_identifier(), monster_gender(), None]
        monster[i][2] = monster_name(monster[i][1])



    return monster
```

The output of this code is for number = 3 for example

```
[[3, 'Male', 'Berid'], 0, 0]
```

but should be something like this

```
[[1,'Male','Berid'],[2,'Female','David'],[3,'Male','Holger']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop:

```
for i in monster:
```

iterates over the *values* in the `monster` list. You are not getting indices, as Python loops are [*foreach* constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop).

Your list only contains the number `0`:

```
monster = [0] * number
```

so all `i` is ever set to is `0`. This in turn is why you only ever alter the element at index 0, everywhere you wrote `monster[i]` you could have written `monster[0]` for the same results.

Rather than pre-build the list with zeros, just use [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to add new elements as you loop, and use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) to count out how many monsters you create:

```
def create_monsters(number):
    monsters = []   # empty list

    for i in range(number):  # loop number times
        gender = monster_gender()
        monster = [monster_identifier(), gender, monster_name(gender)]
        monsters.append(monster)  # add to the list at the end    

    return monsters
```

I renamed the function and list to the plural `monsters` to indicate this is not just about 1 monster.

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem this quick it actually helped me much understanding Python! Also thank you for fixing my ugly workaround, I never really coded and am just starting. Its hard, I dont understand much but I try my best and people like you help me much.

When I finish my project I'll be happy to mention you for your help!

Comment: +1 for renaming to 'monsters'. 90% of these questions would not exist if people named things for what they were rather than what they hope the value might be.

Answer (score 1):

simply replace

```
monster = [0] * number
```

with

```
monster = range(number)
```